# netezza nzsql script INSERT output

Tags: netezza

if this is my output to the terminal from an nzsql insert command being read from a file:

INSERT 0 1

what does the 0 mean?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0 indicates that the insert ran successfully with no error.

This is documented in the [reference material here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_insert.html)

Comment: thanks a lot. that was my guess, but in trying to confirm i googled my apparently useless heart out to no avail.